# DataFrame.resample() - use the last existing index value, not the last value in the date range, for each group

Tags: python, pandas

Sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [-0.15, -0.22, -0.13, -0.20, -0.12, 0.24, -0.06, 0.09, 0.20, -0.12],
        [0.10, 0.14, -0.21, 0.04, 0.18, 0.06, -0.08, 0.18, 0.12, -0.06],
        [0.06, 0.13, -0.21, 0.01, -0.12, 0.16, -0.12, -0.25, 0.24, -0.04],
        [0.01, -0.10, 0.01, 0.00, 0.19, -0.12, 0.07, -0.14, 0.02, -0.03],
        [-0.14, -0.16, -0.05, 0.18, -0.06, 0.07, 0.03, -0.20, -0.07, 0.20],
        [-0.13, -0.04, -0.04, -0.12, 0.14, -0.03, 0.16, 0.06, 0.18, -0.15],
        [-0.22, 0.15, 0.10, -0.22, 0.19, 0.05, -0.18, -0.14, 0.14, 0.13],
        [0.13, -0.23, -0.08, 0.03, -0.04, -0.17, -0.25, 0.24, -0.13, -0.21],
        [-0.07, 0.05, -0.16, 0.05, 0.18, -0.01, -0.11, 0.15, 0.21, 0.17],
    ],
    index=pd.to_datetime(
        [
            "2020-01-02",
            "2020-01-03",
            "2020-01-31",
            "2020-02-03",
            "2020-02-04",
            "2020-02-28",
            "2020-03-02",
            "2020-03-03",
            "2020-03-13",
        ]
    ),
    columns=list("abcdefghij"),
)
```

In this data, I want to group by month, and return the last row in each month.

My first naive attempt was:

```py
last_trading_day = df.resample('1M').last()
```

But this caused the index values in `last_trading_day` to be the *last calendar day of each month*, and this is not what I want. I want *the last day that was actually present in the data*.

I get the same results if I use:

```py
df.resample('1M').agg(lambda grp: grp.loc[grp.index.max()])
```

or:

```py
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).last()
```

However, using `.tail` instead of `.last` worked!

```py
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M'), sort=True).tail(1)
```

But I don't understand why this (and only this) works, while none of the other options work. Is there a general principle here that I am missing?

Moreover, in general, is there a way to control how index labels are assigned in `.resample` output?

Comment: I don't see a reason why `.resample(...).tail()` should not be implemented.  Please consider [opening](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) a feature request issue on that specific point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Difference between last() and tail(1)

Regarding your first question: What is the difference between `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).last()` and `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M'), sort=True).tail(1)`?

Let's dissect the statements. First a `pd.Grouper` object is created.

```py
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M'))
```

This `pd.Grouper` object has its own datetime-based index, but no values. The values are calculated on the `pd.Grouper` object.

If we call `last()` on the `pd.Grouper` object, it will do exactly what the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) says

> **Compute** last of group values. (my emphasis)

It returns the last value of each group, but it will use the index of the `pd.Grouper` object. Sidenote: Any calculation such as `mean()` or `max()` will return the grouper index.

The `tail()` method does not calculate anything, it just [returns the last row(s)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html).

> **Return** last n rows of each group. (my emphasis)

In both cases you get the same values. The relevant distinction for the index is calculation vs. no calculation.

### How to control index labels in groupings?

> Moreover, in general, is there a way to control how index labels are assigned in .resample output

There are some ways how you can control the grouper bins by creating the grouper object ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)). But they are somewhat limited. As far as I know there is no option for your use case.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that you were willing to pick a part my two-part question instead of voting to close :) It sounds like the only option for the general case is to either loop over groups and build the output manually with `pd.concat`, or to run the `agg` operation but calculate the desired index separately and use that to overwrite the index of the former.

Comment: By the way, I think the difference is that `tail` is a special case by design. According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html): "it returns a subset of rows from the original `DataFrame` with original index and order preserved (`as_index` flag is ignored)."